# SCSS !default with css-modules

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, sass, tsx

*I was about to ask it here but I found an answer while looking at the similar questions it's listed, so I'll answer myself hopefully will help others*

It's about using the `!default` with SCSS.
A simple usage would be:

#### Project A

*_define.scss:*

```
$text-color: #1c1c1c !default;
$button-background-color: deepskyblue !default;
```

*core.scss:*

```
@import "define";

html, body
{
    color: $text-color;
}
```

*button.scss:*

```
.button
{
    background-color: $button-background-color;
}
```

*button.tsx:* *(using css-modules-typescript-loader)*

```
import style from "./button.scss";

const Button = () => (
    <button className={style.button}></button>
);
```

#### Project B

*_define_override.scss:*

```
$text-color: #2c2c2c;
$button-background-color: tomato;
```

*style.scss:*

```
// Note that the override file is first.
@import "define_override";
@import "../Project A/core";
```

Now when using **style.scss** in Project B the **_define_override.scss** will override the text color of the Project A. But, it won't override the button's background color and this is because I'm using the *css-modules*.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it using [sass-resources-loader](https://github.com/shakacode/sass-resources-loader) where I created in Project B a file e.g. named `_define.scss` which will have:

```
$text-color: #2c2c2c;
$button-background-color: tomato;
```

And added it to the loader:

```
{
    loader: "sass-resources-loader",
    options:
    {
        resources: path.resolve(PROJECT_ROOT, "src/theme/_define.scss")
    }
}
```